# How to save huge encoded data into .h5 files to store and use later?

Tags: encoding, huggingface-transformers

I am working on encoding a huge dataset using HuggingFace Transformer LayoutLMv3. However, my dataset has around 20,000 files, and after I encoded, I want to compress and store to use later. I tried to use Python Pickle, but it only supports up to 2GB. My file is around 4-5GB. I also used .h5 to compress, but when I re-open the .h5 file, it does not allow me to use to train the model.

Are there any solution can I use to compress? Thanks

I am expected to find a solution to decompress my .h5 file, or find another way to compress my encoded data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].